# Brightcove AWS S3 upload returning InvalidAccessKeyId in Coldfusion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coldfusion

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
    <Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>ASIAJSDFW27523RELDJA</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <RequestId>22F0A23F675424D0</RequestId>
    <HostId>3ozDoKHMzf00wlsdfA0hsdfWDrzy21c0xqxwOwd1BJo8MqSouPZU</HostId>
</Error>
```

For accessKeyID, I am using the value access_key_id returned by GET to https://ingest.api.brightcove.com/v1/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}/videos/{VIDEO_ID}/upload-urls/{SOURCE_NAME}

Since I want to use multi-part upload, I followed guidelines provided by the following URLs.
http://blog.tcs.de/coldfusion-amazon-s3-upload-via-form-post-example/
https://aws.amazon.com/items/1434?externalID=1434

using s3.cfc from https://github.com/joedanz/cf-amazon-s3

For policy:

```
{"expiration": {add 1 day to now}",
    "conditions": [
        {"bucket": bucket-name-from-brightcove},
        ["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"],
        {"acl": "authenticated-read"},
        {"success_action_redirect": "my-server-redirect-url"},
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "#mData.fileType#"],
        ["content-length-range", 0, #mData.fileSize#]
    ]
}
```

My CF code:

```
rStruct['policy'] = ToBase64(s3policy);
s3 = createObject("component", 's3').init('access_key_id-from-brightcove','secret_access_key-from-brightcove');
rStruct['signature'] = s3.createSignature(rStruct['policy']);
rStruct['auth'] = 'authenticated-read';
rStruct['s3URL'] = 'https://bucket-name-from-brightcove.s3.amazonaws.com/';   
rStruct['s3redirectURL'] = 'my-server-redirect-url';
```

my form like: (I am replacing hidden field values with jquery)

```
<form name="dlgform" id="dlgform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" target="submitDialog_submitFrame">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" id="key" value="uploads/${filename}">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" id="AWSAccessKeyId" value="access_key_id-from-brightcove">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" id="acl" value="authenticated-read">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" id="success_action_redirect" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" id="policy" value="rStruct['policy']">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" id="signature" value="rStruct['signature']">
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" id="Content-Type" value="file-content-type">
     File: <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
</form>
```

Comment: Which region are you trying to upload to? Regions deployed after January 2014 only support AWS Signature V4. I don't believe that the S3 wrapper CFC you are using to do the signing supports AWS Signature V4 either.

Comment: brightcove site says:
Currently DI can only pull media from regions that are configured for AWS Signature Version 2. Until further notice, please use one of these regions.

Answer (score 1):

Access Key IDs beginning with the characters `ASIA` are associated with temporary credentials from STS and always have an accompanying `X-Amz-Security-Token` that must be embedded in any request signed by these credentials.

Without this token embedded in the request, AWS endpoints will not even recognize the Access Key ID and the `does not exist in our records` error is expected.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html

This error is unrelated to Signature Version 4. It also affects Signature Version 2, which is what the code in the question is using.